# Replace database command line cron job

Tags: mysql, cron

I'm new to cron jobs and I need to reset a database on my server every Monday at 12:00 PM, i have a sql dump file which should be used. I searched and found that i have to drop the database first ,create it again and import. I tried this command below but got this error "sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo"

```
sudo mysql -uusername -ppassword database --force < /var/www/vhosts/mysite/httpdocs/folder/db_dmp/dump.sql
```

Comment: Change the contents of the `.sql` file to include the desired `DROP` commands?

Comment: Okay so i took care of that. I scheduled the task but got this error "sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo". I'm using the follwing command line : sudo mysql -uusername -ppassword database --force  < /var/www/vhosts/mysite/httpdocs/folder/db_dmp/dump.sql